# Unable to match results of php hash_hmac() and coldfusion hmac()

Tags: php, hash, coldfusion, sha256

I am working on encrypting a URL and converting a working script from PHP to ColdFusion. I have completed 95% of the work but I am stuck at this point after trying many solutions available on StackOverflow. My results are still not matching. I confirmed the `saltBin` and `keyBin` values are the same on both scripts. Please have a look.

PHP version

```
$saltBin = R�k��E�x^ �O<�-�7J=S�z��� �;
$keyBin = �;B��|� �0U,��h�NS+��.��G���

res = hash_hmac('sha256', $saltBin, $keyBin);
result
39ddcd6156a30fdcebc9fbf5dd59a0ef4f47e27841bbc12ce72b64a0a63c0324
```

Coldfusion version

```
<cfset res = hmac(saltBin,keyBin,"HMACSHA256")>
result
30A658BEB3965C2D7D27A3F717FB6C13B05ED44E8B2A5A7FEBB9B57887CF57A0
```

I have tried the following solutions

[ColdFusion equivalent to PHP hash_hmac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331980/coldfusion-equivalent-to-php-hash-hmac)

[coldfusion hashing and difference between hmacSHA256 and SHA256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977333/coldfusion-hashing-and-difference-between-hmacsha256-and-sha256)

**Update:**

Below is an abbreviated version of the [PHP version](https://pastebin.com/m9zemNvU)

```
$key = '943b421c9eb07c830af81030552c86009268de4e532ba2ee2eab8247c6da0881';
$salt = '520f986b998545b4785e0defbc4f3c1203f22de2374a3d53cb7a7fe9fea309c5';
$keyBin = pack("H*" , $key);
$saltBin = pack("H*" , $salt);
$path = "/rs:fill:300:300:1/g:no/aHR0cDovL2ltZy5leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9wcmV0dHkvaW1hZ2UuanBn.png";
echo hash_hmac('sha256', $saltBin.$path, $keyBin);
```

Result: `7062c2b5786c82de963767de4b0cdbc4e7ed7db2ce7466708bf8a28d8572888b`

[ColdFusion version](https://pastebin.com/81QzVjQZ)

```
<cfset key = '943b421c9eb07c830af81030552c86009268de4e532ba2ee2eab8247c6da0881'>
<cfset salt = '520f986b998545b4785e0defbc4f3c1203f22de2374a3d53cb7a7fe9fea309c5'>
<cfset keyBin = binaryDecode(key, 'hex')>  
<cfset keyBin =  toString(keyBin)>
<cfset saltBin = binaryDecode(salt, 'hex')>  
<cfset saltBin =  toString(saltBin)>
<cfset path =  "/rs:fill:300:300:1/g:no/aHR0cDovL2ltZy5leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9wcmV0dHkvaW1hZ2UuanBn.png">
<cfset result = hmac(saltBin&path,keyBin,"HMACSHA256")>
<cfoutput>#result#</cfoutput>
```

Result: `FFA7A526BB464CA1470F309605F1ED63832342B704F8475BFAF26CCD1092603B`

Can anyone please help me in this regard?

Thanks.

Comment: We need to see the code showing how `$saltBin` and `$keyBin` are actually populated.  Also, when dealing with binary, it's better to post values as base64 encoded strings [base64_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php).  What's the base64 encoded value of `$saltBin` and `$keyBin` ?

Comment: @SOS I have added the full scripts in the links at the end of the question. Please check.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66079528/2645359

Comment: No idea why someone voted to close this question as "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more". It's clearly about a specific code problem, with code samples and results provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> saltBin and keyBin values are the same on both scripts

Yes, those values are the same, but the *data* being hashed isn't. That's why the results don't match.

The php code hashes the concatenated *binary* of the salt and path variables. To illustrate using a simple values:

| Data | Value | Binary | Base64 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Salt | ab | [-85] | qw== |
| Path | 123 | [49,50,51] | MTIz |
| Salt + Path | n/a | **[-85,49,50,51]** | qzEyMw== |

Whereas the CF code uses the binary of the concatenated *strings* salt and path, after some very ... dubious re-encoding with [ToString()](https://cfdocs.org/tostring). As you can see, the resulting binary is very different than what's used by php:

| Data | Value | Binary | Base64 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Salt | � | [-17,-65,-67] | 77+9 |
| Path | 123 | [49,50,51] | MTIz |
| Salt + Path | �123 | **[-17,-65,-67,49,50,51]** | 77+9MTIz |

The CF code needs to concatenate the *binary* of the two variables. Then pass that binary to the [hmac()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-h-im/hmac.html) function:

**CF** (see [runnable example](https://trycf.com/gist/b954d74741a9d08c50c4ac6210c0bcf7/lucee5?theme=monokai))

```
<cfscript>
   key = '943b421c9eb07c830af81030552c86009268de4e532ba2ee2eab8247c6da0881';
   salt = '520f986b998545b4785e0defbc4f3c1203f22de2374a3d53cb7a7fe9fea309c5';
   keyBin =  binaryDecode(key, "hex");
   saltBin = binaryDecode(salt, "hex");
   path = "/rs:fill:300:300:1/g:no/aHR0cDovL2ltZy5leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9wcmV0dHkvaW1hZ2UuanBn.png";
   pathBin = charsetDecode(path, "utf-8");

   // merge binary of salt and path
   combined = [];
   combined.append(saltBin, true);
   combined.append(pathBin, true);
   result = lcase(hmac( javacast("byte[]", combined),keyBin,"HMACSHA256"));
   writeDump(result);
</cfscript>
```

*Result:* `7062c2b5786c82de963767de4b0cdbc4e7ed7db2ce7466708bf8a28d8572888b`

**PHP** (see [runnable example](https://onlinephp.io/c/4ca13))

```
<?php
$key = '943b421c9eb07c830af81030552c86009268de4e532ba2ee2eab8247c6da0881';
$salt = '520f986b998545b4785e0defbc4f3c1203f22de2374a3d53cb7a7fe9fea309c5';
$keyBin = pack("H*" , $key);
$saltBin = pack("H*" , $salt);
$path = "/rs:fill:300:300:1/g:no/aHR0cDovL2ltZy5leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9wcmV0dHkvaW1hZ2UuanBn.png";
echo hash_hmac('sha256', $saltBin.$path, $keyBin);
```

*Result:* `7062c2b5786c82de963767de4b0cdbc4e7ed7db2ce7466708bf8a28d8572888b`

Comment: Wonderful and well explained answer! Deserves way more than one upvote!

Comment: @SOS Thank you so much. You saved my time and energy and resolved the issue. Great explanation and Wonderful answer. I have applied your solution and It is working like a charm. Great!!!